# HP fan-fiction about Harry Potter, a Witch Nurse and Ginny

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I recall reading some 8 or 9 years ago a good fan-fiction story online about Harry suffering a mishap and getting injured while testing a prototype of a new Nimbus with Captain Oliver Wood for "old time's sake". I don't remember if I read in fanfiction.net or archiveofourown.org or another place.

I believe the plot took place during the Deadly Hallows before the Battle of Hogwarts. Harry is sent to St Mungo's Hospital for treatment where he is cared to by a lovely witch nurse. Ginny detects a bond between the nurse and Harry during one of her visits. Then, a jealous Ginny informs Hermione about it. They both ask Hagrid for his assistance. Rubeus tries to steal, I think, a Wiggenweld Potion from Snape's office in order to help Harry recuperate faster, but he fails due to the use of a wrong password to enter Snape's office.

I barely remember Harry having nightmares with a Thestral but I remember that at the end of the story it is revealed that the nurse was sent by Voldemort so that Harry didn't interfere with Voldemort's "battle plan" to take over Hogwarts. With the help, again, of Hagrid, Ginny and Hermione, riding a winged horse or pegasus, manages to halt the nurse's journey to the hospital (I believe with a spell to block the nurse's daily trip) long enough for Harry to recuperate and reconnect with his friends.

The story was so engaging that I'd love to read it again.

Comment: You can also try asking this on HPFanfiction subreddit. Is the nurse complicit in the plan? Does anyone outside the Death Eaters ever suspect her? Is the delay repetitive, or is it a one-time that allows Harry to get out of his condition?